# The use of a constant in the middle pattern - ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm trying to pass in the middle of pattern / regex constant.
The script takes a variable(folder name) from the command line, by ARGV [0].

```
TEST = ARGV[0]
```

I want to put this variable to the pattern, but I'm not sure how it should look in correct syntax. I'm trying something like that.

```
KEY = /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\/#{TEST}\/test/
```

Comment: can you give an example of a case to tell us what you should get? I dont follow you completely

Comment: Constant KEY should allowed me to find the correct folder with a specific file. Depending on the situation, I have to appeal to different subfolders. 
Constant TEST should be the name of the folder. For example, `1.0.32 / folder / test`, where the `folder` is given by a constant TEST.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have? if `ARGV[0] == "folder"` then the regex would be correct as `/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\/folder\/test/` given that what ever you are testing against starts the line with `1.0.32` but since we have no idea what type of input you are using to test `KEY` against it is very difficult to help.

Comment: The problem is that I have several folders and I want to put folder name to the pattern, from the command line. For example, `ruby script.rb TEST = folder` .I need to be able to adjust.

Comment: Currently my code causes that the pattern is invalid. I can not download the file test.

Comment: Try `/^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\/#{Regexp.escape(TEST)}\/test/`. Still, you have not provided more data: what is an example of the folder name that fails?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your pattern, maybe you're having difficulty to test, so find  below  a way to test it:

```
TEST = 'foo_bar'

KEY = /^[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\/#{TEST}\/test/

puts ( '0.1.2/foo_bar/test'.match KEY ).inspect

puts ( '1.2.3/foo_bar/foo_bar'.match KEY).inspect
```

You can see that the first puts statement prints the match, the second prints `nil`

Hope this helps